# React-Admin: How to redirect to a specified `list` after hitting 'save' on a custom route

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom route:

```
  <Route
    exact
    path="/assetsBulkCreate"
    component={ComponentWithPermissions(AssetsBulkCreate)}
  />
```

It is used to create assets in bulk:

```
export const AssetsBulkCreate = ({permissions, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <Create
      resource="assets/bulkInsert"
 ...
```

This works.

However, after we hit save the page is redirected to the Dashboard.

I would like to redirect it to the `list` of the resource `assets` (which is a different resource).

**How can this be done?**

P.S. The `redirect` prop does not let us specify a different resource, so I cannot use `list` as value there (it does not even work because the custom route does not have a list).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `redirect` prop also accept a function. See the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#redirection-after-submission)

For example:

```
const redirect = (basePath, id, data) => `/author/${data.author_id}/show`;

export const PostEdit = (props) => {
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm redirect={redirect}>
            ...
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: Hello @Gildas-Garcia, can I use redirect in my case? I need to list the result of another endpoint when a user click in a list.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931110/how-can-i-list-data-from-another-endpoint-inside-show-option-in-react-admin

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the `list` view. See [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#redirection-after-submission)

```js
export const PostCreate = (props) => {
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm redirect="list">
            ...
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactAdmin got updated, and now the redirect property is a child of the Create/Edit component.

```
export const PostCreate = (props) => {
    <Create {...props} redirect="list">
        <SimpleForm>
            ...
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```