# How can I list data from another endpoint inside show option in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, json-server

React-Admin version: **2.4.0**

I have a list with a info of wallets that I can list using this endpoint:

```
http://myHost:8080/api/v1/private/wallets
```

Now I want to show data of the movements of each wallet when I click in the wallet of the list.

So, for obtain the data of the movements of the wallet I need to call to another endpoint, sending the get with this format:

```
${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}/movements
```

For example:

```
http://myHost:8080/api/v1/private/wallets/cd496094-a77a-4e4e-bcd9-3361ff89294a/movements
```

This endpoint return me an object like this:

```
{
   "_embedded": {
       "movements": [
           {
               "id": "ftr4e2e5-a2bf-49f7-9206-3e2deff3a456",
               "amount": 10,
               "status": "PENDING"
           },
           {
               "id": "67732ad9-233e-42be-8079-11efe4d158yt",
               "amount": 2.56,
               "status": "SUCCESS"
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

I have this code:

```
//IMPORTS
export const WalletList = props => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid rowClick="show">
      <TextField source="id" label="Wallet ID" />
      <TextField source="iban" label="IBAN" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);

export const WalletShow = props => (
  <Show {...props}>
    <TabbedShowLayout>
      <Tab label="Wallet">
        <TextField label="Wallet ID" source="id" />
      </Tab>
      <Tab label="Movements">
        <TextField label="Movement ID" source="id" />
      </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

I have a custom data provider based in json-server for this endpoint:

```
export default (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson) => {

  const convertDataRequestToHTTP = (type, resource, params) => {
    let url = '';
    const options = {};
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST: {
        //...
      }
      case GET_ONE:
         // custom call for movements: /api/v1/private/wallets/{walletId}/movements
        if (resource === 'wallets') {
          url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}/movements`;
          break;
        }
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        break;
      case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
        //...
      case UPDATE:
        //...
      case CREATE:
        //...
      case DELETE:
        //...
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported fetch action type ${type}`);
    }
    return { url, options };
  };
  //...
}
```

And my error is:

```
The response to 'GET_ONE' must be like { data: { id: 123, ... } }, but the received data does not have an 'id' key. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'GET_ONE'
```

How I can list inside a show component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about your `dataProvider`, as explained in the [documentation(https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#response-format), you must return an object with a `data` key containing your API response. This will fix the error you're seeing.

Second, about having a list of related data inside a show view, you should use a [`ReferenceManyField`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield) inside your tab. It will requests all `movements` linked to the current `wallet` using the `GET_MANY_REFERENCE` fetch type.